# How to generate the following json data using prototype.js?

Tags: json, prototypejs

How to generate the following json data using prototype.js?

```
var testData=[{
                name: 'Year 1800',
                data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'Year 1900',
                data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
            }, {
                name: 'Year 2008',
                data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
            }];
```

Comment: Can you clarify - do you want to see the javascript variables that represent this JSON data or do you want to know how to convert this data to JSON?

Comment: i need to know the javascript variables that represent this JSON data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.toJSON(testData);`